# Describing a frame as "thin" or "bold"

Tags: meaning

I need to describe the thickness of an image frame. Is it correct to say *this frame is **thin** and that one is **bold***?

Comment: Is there a reason not to say _this frame is "thick"_?

Comment: Would "narrow" and "broad" not be a better choice of words?

Comment: @Hainsey: a narrow frame fits a narrow (but long) picture. A thin frame may be quite broad but the borders it creates around the picture will be thin.

Comment: "Bold" is a term from typography. It is possible that it would be understood in this context, especially if it is contrasted with, say "thin"; but it may not be understood at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use just about any adjective to describe a frame; some are [**thin**](http://www.stockphotopro.com/photo-thumbs-2/AH2821.jpg), some are [**bold**](http://asianlifestyledesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/red-frame.jpg), and some are [**ornate**](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lptdm6tYKG1qz9k9v.jpg). If you are referring primarily to width, however, the opposite of "*thin*" would be "*thick*," in most contexts.

*Narrow* and *wide* might work, too.